# How to clean ambiguous folder paths created while mounting shared folders in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, shared-partition

I didn't know how to phrase this question better. I hope the following description is clear.
I have Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon installed alongside Windows 10, on a dual-boot system. Between the two OS, I have a shared partition, named `DATA`, where I put files that I may need to access from either of the OS. This drive/partition, DATA, is located at `/media/username` folder in Linux.
Now, I need to access a remote folder and its subfolders, kept on our server. Let's say, the shared folder is at `//192.168.100.100/OurSharedFolder` with several subfolders. I thought to map/mount this remote folder to a location on my DATA drive, more specifically, at `/media/username/DATA/Projects/MappedFolders`.

One important detail. The above address and OurSharedFolder are accessible only when I am connected via VPN.

To permanently map this network folder was easy in Windows 10. To do this on Linux, I followed simple steps given at [this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=288534), in the "Permanent mount" section.
Basically, created and saved a credentials file using

`sudo nano /root/.smbcredentials`

and also saved the mount path configuration in `fstab` file

`//192.168.100.100/OurSharedFolder /media/username/DATA/Projects/MappedFolders cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Then I created the `MappedFolders` folder at the `/media/username/DATA/Projects/` location. Finally, I executed

`mount -a`

This created the desired mounted drive. So far so good.

But the problem started when I changed the name of the MappedFolders folder to SharedFolders.
I changed the physical folder name, as well as the path in the fstab file. Then executed `mount -a` again.
It created the mount folder, but automatically, the location of my "Projects" folder, which is inside the shared drive DATA, changed from `/media/username/DATA/Projects/` to `/media/username/DATA1/Projects/`.

I unmounted using the

`umount -a -t cifs`

but, the `DATA1` alias remained.
I changed back the mounted folder's name to `MappedFolders` as earlier, and mounted again, and now there is `DATA`, `DATA1` and `DATA2`.
They all point to `DATA`. But it has changed the location of my Projects folder to `DATA2`.

In short, for each `mount` and `umount` operation, it created a new shortcut for `DATA` drive.

The implication is that now the datafiles inside the Projects folder have a new path, and broken links in the files that access those datafiles.

I hope I am clear in my description.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after consulting with a colleague, found a workaround. Posting here just in case if someone faces a similar problem in future.

The problem is (was) that the Linux automatically assigns a mount name. The solution is to give a fixed name for mounting.

First, I deleted the redundant copies of `DATA`, the ones which had a blank folder I had created for mounting. In my case, these were `DATA` and `DATA1` folders.

`sudo rm -rf DATA`

`DATA2` had the folders of my original `DATA` drive. So I kept it as it is.
Then, I opened the Disk program from Linux menu. Selected the `DATA` partition (yes, it kept the original name).

[image]

Clicking on the "Additional partition options" button found below the Volumes, it opened a context menu. From this menu, I selected "Edit Mount Options".
The next are the following changes.

1. Set "User Session Defaults" to `OFF` (in order to make changes to the default settings).
2. In the option "Identify As", I selected `LABEL=DATA`.
   This will hard-define the mount label as `DATA`, for the current and all future mountings.

[image]

That's it. Rebooting the system brought back the `DATA` partition mount name.
One small difference. The path of the DATA was not anymore `/media/username/DATA`, but instead `/mnt/DATA`.
I found this setting even better (than `/media/username`), hence I kept it that way. Just fixed the broken file addressing in my program configuration.